# When would a Python float lose precision when cast to Protobuf/C++ float?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I'm interested in minimising the size of a protobuf message serialised from Python.

Protobuf has floats (4 bytes) and doubles (8 bytes). Python has a float type that's actually a C double, at least in CPython.

My question is: given an instance of a Python `float`, is there a "fast" way of checking if the value would lose precision if it was assigned to a protobuf `float` (or really a C++ float) ?

Comment: That's not possible in my use case. I'm testing the values and assigning to a `oneof` field.

Comment: Bah, the duplicate was actually incorrect, sorry. That allows you to convert a float to a double without ending up with infinity. You can still loose precision.

Comment: How fast does it need to be? One possible approach would be to use either the `struct` module or NumPy to round-trip the value through float32 and see if you get the same value back. But it's not clear to me whether either of those counts as "fast". (At least if you use NumPy, you can check many floats at once fairly efficiently.)

Comment: Also, are the floats all within a reasonable range? Do you need to check for the exponent being out of bounds for `float32`, or is only the significand likely to be an issue?

Comment: @MarkDickinson thanks. A bit like this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3240014/57215, would need to look into the performance characteristics though

Comment: @MarkDickinson unfortunately I don't control the input at all. The exponent might indeed be outside the bounds of a `float32`. I'm wondering if the `as_integer_ratio()` method on a float might be useful at all?

Comment: @MarkNS: So if you need to process *lots* of these floats (which I'm assuming you do, if performance is an issue), then it *might* pay off to use NumPy to batch process them. Wrap all the floats you care about up in an array `x`, and then do `x.astype(np.float32) == x`. But the wrapping part might be costly. You'd need to time.

Comment: Is the space the reason you can't just define them all as `double`s in the `.proto`?

Comment: @AdamBarnes indeed, as I mention the double takes twice as many bytes as the float, and I'm trying to minimise the message size where possible.

Comment: Protobuf defines a message as a collection of types, though, so you'd need `2**n` different types of message, where `n` is the number of floats in it, right?  And the receiver would have to deal with that?  I think I'm missing something, sorry.

Comment: @MarkDickinson thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately it's not possible to easily batch here, as they are values in a heterogeneous object grid. I can't for example take a column, and expect all values to be of one type.

Comment: @AdamBarnes no I have a oneof field with a dblvalue and a floatvalue (amongst other value types)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check convert the float to a hex representation; the sign, exponent and fraction each get a separate section. Provided the fraction uses only the first 6 hex digits (the remaining 7 digits must be zero), *and* the 6th digit is even (so the last bit is *not* set) will your 64-bit double float fit in a 32-bit single. The exponent is limited to a value between -126 and 127:

```
import math
import re

def is_single_precision(
        f,
        _isfinite=math.isfinite,
        _singlepat=re.compile(
            r'-?0x[01]\.[0-9a-f]{5}[02468ace]0{7}p'
            r'(?:\+(?:1[01]\d|12[0-7]|[1-9]\d|\d)|'
            r'-(?:1[01]\d|12[0-6]|[1-9]\d|\d))$').match):
    return not _isfinite(f) or _singlepat(f.hex()) is not None or f == 0.0
```

The `float.hex()` method is quite fast, faster than roundtripping via struct or numpy; you can create 1 million hex representations in under half a second:

```
>>> timeit.Timer('(1.2345678901e+26).hex()').autorange()
(1000000, 0.47934128501219675)
```

The regex engine is also pretty fast, and with name lookups optimised in the function above we can test 1 million float values in about 1.1 seconds:

```
>>> import random, sys
>>> testvalues = [0.0, float('inf'), float('-inf'), float('nan')] + [random.uniform(sys.float_info.min, sys.float_info.max) for _ in range(2 * 10 ** 6)]
>>> timeit.Timer('is_single_precision(f())', 'from __main__ import is_single_precision, testvalues; f = iter(testvalues).__next__').autorange()
(1000000, 1.1044921400025487)
```

The above works because the *binary32* format for floats allots 23 bits for the fraction. The exponent is allotted 8 bits (signed). The regex only allows for the first 23 bits to be set, and the exponent to be within the range for a signed 8-bit number.

Also see

- [IEEE 754 single-precision binary floating-point format: binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32)
- [IEEE 754 double-precision binary floating-point format: binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64)

This may not be what you want however! Take for example 1/3rd or 1/10th. Both are values which require *approximation* in floating point values, and both fail the test:

```
>>> (1/3).hex()
'0x1.5555555555555p-2'
>>> (1/10).hex()
'0x1.999999999999ap-4'
```

You may have to instead take a heuristic approach; if your hex value has all zeros in the first 6 digits of the fraction, or an exponent outside of the (-126, 127) range, converting to double would lead to *too much* loss.

Comment: This doesn't *quite* capture the right bits, unfortunately. We need to know whether the binary value is expressible in <= 24 bits, and the `hex` output format gives one leading bit and then bits in multiples of 4. (For a concrete example, consider `x = float.fromhex("0x1.921fb5")`, which passes the zeros check, but isn't exactly representable in `float32` format.)

Comment: @MarkDickinson: grumble. Trying to find confirmation but must admit to being inexperienced with the hex format.

Comment: Thanks! I've got some research to do to get my head around this.. I'll be writing some tests I guess. @MarkDickinson, do you have a example where this test would be incorrect?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: So I think checking that the hex digit at position `9` is even, on top of the check you already have, should work. Though it's annoying that that can't be translated directly to a check on the parity of the `ord` of the character.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: yup, was getting to that conclusion too, updating.

Comment: I get `False` for `is_single_precision(0.0)`. Looks like another special case to fix...

Comment: @MarkDickinson: bah, 0.0 is `'0x0.0p+0'` in hex. Compare that to 1.0... Why would you ever be consistent..

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Apologies. When I implemented `float.hex`, I was following Java for this special case. (You can see the discussion at https://bugs.python.org/issue3008.)

Comment: @MarkDickinson: yay, we can blame Java! Python's sanity has been redeemed. :-)

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, here is the *"round tripping through struct"* method mentioned in the comments, which has the benefit of not requiring numpy but still giving accurate results:

```
import struct, math
def is_single_precision_struct(x, _s=struct.Struct("f")):
    return math.isnan(x) or _s.unpack(_s.pack(x))[0] == x
```

Time comparison against `is_single_precision_numpy()`:

- is_single_precision_numpy(f): [2.5650789737701416, 2.5488431453704834, 2.551704168319702]
- is_single_precision_struct(f): [0.3972139358520508, 0.39684605598449707, 0.39119601249694824]

So it also seems to be faster on my machine.

Comment: Nice, indeed it's also faster than Martijn's hex/regex example on my machine using his test case. It does return `False` for nan, but that's fixed with the `math.isnan` test as in the other answers. Many thanks.

Comment: Nice indeed. You can shave off a bit more time by using an appropriate `struct.Struct` instance directly: that is, set `s = struct.Struct("f")`, then use `_pack=s.pack`, `_unpack=s.unpack`, and `return _unpack(_pack(x))[0] == x`. Using a dedicated `struct.Struct` instance gave a 29% speedup on my machine.

Comment: @MarkDickinson, MarkNS: Thanks for the improvements!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a simple solution that covers *almost* all corner cases, and will correctly detect out-of-range exponents as well as loss of information from the smaller precision, you can use NumPy to convert your potential float into an `np.float32` object, then compare with the original:

```
import numpy

def is_single_precision_numpy(floatval, _float32=np.float32):
    return _float32(floatval) == floatval
```

This automatically takes care of potentially problematic cases like values that are in the `float32` subnormal range. For example:

```
>>> is_single_precision_numpy(float.fromhex('0x13p-149'))
True
>>> is_single_precision_numpy(float.fromhex('0x13.8p-149'))
False
```

Those cases are harder to deal with easily with the `hex`-based solution.

While not as fast as @Martijn Pieters' regex-based solution, the speed is still respectable (about half as fast as the regex-based solution). Here are timings (where `is_single_precision_re_hex` is exactly the version from Martijn's answer).

```
>>> timeit.Timer('is_single_precision_numpy(f)', 'f = 1.2345678901e+26; from __main__ import is_single_precision_numpy').repeat(3, 10**6)
[2.035495020012604, 2.0115931580075994, 2.013475093001034]
>>> timeit.Timer('is_single_precision_re_hex(f)', 'f = 1.2345678901e+26; from __main__ import is_single_precision_re_hex').repeat(3, 10**6)
[1.1169273109990172, 1.1178153319924604, 1.1184561859990936]
```

Unfortunately, while almost all corner cases (subnormals, infinities, signed zeros, overflows, etc.) are handled correctly, there's one corner case that this solution won't work for: the case that `floatval` is a NaN. In that case, `is_single_precision_numpy` will return `False`. That may or may not matter for your needs. If it does matter, then adding an extra `isnan` check should do the trick:

```
import math
import numpy as np

def is_single_precision_numpy(floatval, _float32=np.float32, _isnan=math.isnan):
    return _float32(floatval) == floatval or _isnan(floatval)
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. I have to say that, although I've already accepted the Martijn's answer, I'm more comfortable with this one. I'm willing to trade the performance for the simplicity. Cheers.

Comment: My version now handles infinity and NaN properly (I added that before I saw you answered too). Yours doesn't; `== float('nan')` will of course always fail.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks. Fixed.